# Does the antipode of a f.d. Hopf algebra have finite order

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, conjectures, hopf-algebras

In a lecture I have heard that the antipode of a finite-dimensional Hopf algebra is *conjectured* to be finite, and that this has only been proven in characteristic $0$ by Larson and Radford in 1988. I couldn't find such a result (only stronger statements that the antipode has order $2$ or $4$ in some nice situations). But I have found the older paper

> D. E. Radford, *The antipode of a finite-dimensional Hopf algebra over a field has finite order*. Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 81 (1975), no. 6, 1103--1105

which gives a proof sketch (which I cannot verify) that the conjecture is true in general. **What is the actual status of the conjecture?**

Related (weaker) question: Is the antipode of a finite-dimensional Hopf algebra always invertible? If so, is there an easy proof for this statement, which one can understand without much background? Takeuchi has constructed an infinite-dimensional Hopf algebra whose antipode is not invertible.

Comment: Yes and yes. Since you happen to know German, see Folgerung 2.7 in the III. Kapitel of https://sites.google.com/site/darijgrinberg/hopfalgebren (sorry for the lack of a table of contents; this is an old set of notes and I hadn't really grokked LaTeX back then). Or see Theorem 10.5.6 in Radford's *Hopf Algebras* book. The proof is not easy, but it isn't a tour-de-force either; I found it rather beautiful and surprising. The weaker question is easier to prove; I remember seeing a really short (2 pages?) proof somewhere.

Comment: Here is another paper claiming to give a short proof of the weaker question: http://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~miovanov/Research/H-ant-bij-30-Nov.pdf